# Calculations before extending class

Tags: scala

Here's an imaginary example:

```
class Bottle(volume: Int, water: Int) = {
    def ratio = water / volume.toDouble
}

class RandomFullBottle extends Bottle(foo, foo)
                                       ^    ^
                    these two should be random and equal
```

How do I achieve this, i.e. where to call my `randomBetween(a, b)` function if I don't wanna resort to passing the random value to the `RandomFullBottle` constructor?

Comment: where is foo comes from?

Comment: That's what I should figure out :) I'd like to be able to generate it on the fly before passing it to the `Bottle` constructor.

Comment: If RandomFullBottle does nothing more than having its parameters random, I suggest adding a factory method in companion object instead. `object Bottle { def random() = { val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt(); new Bottle(r, r)  }` and create it using `Bottle.random()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two constructors for your `RandomFullBottle` class:

- A private constructor that takes an int and passes it to the parent `Bottle` constructor
- A public one that takes no arguments, generates the random value and passes it to the private constructor

Like so:

```
class Bottle(volume: Int, water: Int) {
  def ratio = water / volume.toDouble
}

class RandomFullBottle private(amount: Int) extends Bottle(amount, amount) {
  def this() = this(myRandomGenerator())
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot :) The use of `private` in this context is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of convoluted, but this should do it.

```
object Bottle {
  def init(): (Int, Int) = {
    val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt
    (r, r)
  }
}

class Bottle(val volume: Int, val water: Int) {

  def this(vw : (Int, Int)) {
    this(vw._1, vw._2)
  }

  def this() {
    this(Bottle.init())
  }

  def ratio = water / volume.toDouble
}

class RandomFullBottle extends Bottle

val randomBottle = new RandomFullBottle
println(randomBottle.ratio)
println(randomBottle.volume)
println(randomBottle.water)
```